# Python urllib doesn't open any http URL

Tags: python, urllib

On one of my build machine Python urllib doesn't open any http URL, but wget or curl do it well. Also when I ran following script with sudo, I haven't got any error.

Each time I get: Error 111 (connection refused) for any URL

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import urllib.request
x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://pythex.org/')
```

Comment: are you using proxy with wget and curl?

Comment: No, I don't use

Answer (score 0):

Problem was because of invalid HTTP_PROXY was defined in .bashrc